# How to access keys and values of specific index of Map in List without small brackets in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to access  keys and values  in Dart without small brackets. As the values contain link I want String only. How can I achieve it?[The output is with brackets as shown in the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLyFe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop through your code and show all the keys and values

Just loop through your ingredient list then loop through the map using the code below.

```
Map map = {};
map.forEach((key, value) {
  print(key);
  print(value);
});
```